# Understanding verb+ことくらいある

Tags: grammar, particle-くらい

> 教育実習の先生同士、帰る方向が同じなら一緒に帰る**ことくらいある**さ
>   If two student teachers' way home is in the same direction then going home together .?.?

I can't make any sense of the part in bold. Literally "there is the extent of going home together". 
Is there a general grammar pattern to learn here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comes from the 3rd definition [here](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/63287/meaning/m0u/) and expresses the speaker's disdain that they do not go home together despite the fact that their homes are in the same direction. Has the notion of that they should at least be going home together.

Maybe translated as:

> Something like going home together is a given (is supposed to happen/occur)

Comment: Thanks. I'm familiar with that use of くらい. But I always forget that ある can mean 'happen'. That makes perfect sense now.